# Is RoR 'routes' file an alternative for Apache 'mod_rewrite' module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm a starting web developer and the following question is just for the sake of connecting several new things in my brain:
Is RoR 'routes' file an alternative for Apache 'mod_rewrite' module?

Thanks in advance to everyone participating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's similar in that it is a list of url patterns, with each pattern having some rules associated with it.

The main difference is that routes is INTERNAL to Rails:  mod_rewrite will generally come up with a decision for any route, and then serve a file, or pass the request on to another proxy to handle, so can be thought of as a standalone process in the request pipeline.

routes.rb on the other hand can be thought of as something that runs inside Rails and decides which object (where the objects are generally Controllers) should have a method called on it, passing through the request object.  Maybe this isn't exactly what happens but it's something like this.  Rails is like a black box where a request comes in and a response comes out, and routes is inside the box.

So, i guess you could say that it's an alternative to mod_rewrite, because instead of using mod_rewrite you could just get apache to pass all requests to Rails and let Rails (using the routes.rb code) figure it out.  But it's kind of a different thing.

EDIT: i just re-read this and realised it's pretty vague.  Maybe someone else will give a more specific answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes.

The purpose of both of these tools is to map an HTTP request to the appropriate action, based on some properties of the request. Typically these properties are the HTTP method used (`GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc.) and the request URI. Although it has other uses, a typical use case for `mod_rewrite` is to map different URL patterns to different scripts. `routes.rb` on the other hand maps pairs of HTTP methods and URL patterns ("endpoints") to controller methods (it has other ways of expressing these mappings, such as the `resource` method).

The main difference is that `mod_rewrite` always performs this routing logic as part of the Apache web server before control is passed to the client script. `routes.rb` sets up routing logic which is performed internally by Rails. But both achieve the same thing. Rails routing is more portable because you can switch between using Apache, nginx, or the rails server without rewriting your routing logic from scratch each time. Apache rewrite rules tend to be a bit inscrutable, so if you're comfortable with Rails routing by all means use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. They are two different components that serve different purposes.

You can have a Rails application running, without using mod_rewrite, or even Apache. You cannot run a rails application without a routes.rb file.

The Rails routes.rb file is responsible for a few different things. It is where the urls to your resources are generated from. It is also a place where you can mount engines.

For an analogy, consider this:
Routes.rb is the crew responsible for building roads in your application. 
Mod_rewrite is a guy in an orange vest telling you this road is a dead end, follow the detour.